# How to write junit test cases for below exception handling code?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, controller, mockito

```java
@PostMapping("/addCompany")
public Company createCompany(@Valid @RequestBody Company company, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(errors.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return companyService.addCompany(company);
}
```

Comment: You'd just call the `createCompany` method with a mocked `Errors` object… did you try it?

Comment: thankyou for the reply sir, i didnt try with mocked errors object...could you please help me with that???

Answer (score 2):

You can test it in two ways:

- unit test of controller
- web layer test

**Unit test:**

- Mock `Errors` and call `createCompany` with that mock as an argument.
- Verify that exception is thrown

**Web layer test:**

- post an invalid request with `mockMvc`
- check that error code is returned

```java
@WebMvcTest(CompanyController.class)
class CompanyControllerTest {
    private static final String CREATE_COMPANY_ENDPOINT = "/addCompany/";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void respondsWith4xxOnInvalidCreateCompanyRequest() throws Exception {
        String invalidRequest = "{\"id\":\"aaa\", \"name\":\"bbb\"}"
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(CREATE_COMPANY_ENDPOINT)
                .content(invalidRequest)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
                    .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }
}
```

In this case, I have a strong preference to web layer test - you check actual validation logic. Mocking Errors buys you nothing except code coverage.

On top of that:

Your handling of validation errors is trivial. If you drop `Errors` from the parameter list, on invalid input Spring will throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` with `BindingResult`, which has all the data you need.